# React Typescript: readonly: true; ' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make an input field read-only

```
<input type='text' name='email' readonly />
```

The error I get is

```
Type '{ type: string; name: string; readonly: true; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'readonly' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Have you tried readOnly? Make sure the O is a capital.

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReadOnly is the prop that you need to use. Make sure the O is a capital.